# Class Modeling alternatives for Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, model, xcode4, uml

Since the Class Model tool was eliminated in Xcode 4, what other alternatives could you recommend for UML modeling tools for Objective-C?

Comment: Are you looking to create UML diagrams and then generate code from them, or to generate UML diagrams to document existing code?

Comment: Ideally, both. But the first option would suffice too. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

OmniGraffle does UML diagrams.

It doesn't generate code, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use yEd ... not the best solution and does not generate graphs as OmniGraffle can do but at least it can export in SVG and use GraphML files to store the data. (and it is fee)

http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_helpresources.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/download/) which can do it really fast with a [few clicks.](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/276/277/7284_reverseengin.html)

Answer (score 1):

Drop a document folder containing Xcode project file onto OmniGraffle icon on the dock, OmniGraffle will generate UML diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but there is a new tool that did the work for me:

https://github.com/yoshimkd/swift-auto-diagram

The ones mentioned on other posts didn't work.

I hope it helps