# Generate Code with an UML with Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, uml, automatic-ref-counting

Are there any plugins for Xcode or something similar that lets you model your app using UML and generate code for you? I'm programming in Objective-C.

I have found posts that only generate an UML diagram from code, like here:

[Class Modeling alternatives for Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061583/class-modeling-alternatives-for-objective-c)

[How can I generate UML diagrams from Xcode4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079312/how-can-i-generate-uml-diagrams-from-xcode4)

This is not what I'm looking for. I'd like to model my app first, and then generate the code, best would be in Objective-C 3.0 with ARC.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official API for Xcode 4.x plugins. 
You might consider building a tool. 
Depending on the format your UML is in it might be easier to generate text. This could be done with XSLT or any kind of parsing tool. Ruby, Perl, and Python might be quick ways to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried **Enterprise Architect**? Refer the below mentioned link regarding how to represent structure/union etc in diagram and generate code from UML Class diagram.
[UML Class representation for Object Oriented Programming In C](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.0/software_engineering/ooprogrammingusingc.html)

Comment: Question was about Objective-C, not C.