# Create UML Diagram to understand class hierarchy in Xcode

Tags: xcode, uml

I am stuck, i am working on some huge project with not enough documentation, i was thinking if there was a way with which i can generate some UML diagram of my Xcode project to understand it better. I searched a lot and everybody seem to be pretty sure that omnigraffle is the way. But when i try to use it i get this silly alert everytime 
**"This Xcode project can be diagrammed by dragging its containing folder onto the OmniGraffle application icon."**

Can someone help me out on this. I am using the trial version of omnigraffle. Is there some other tool which can help me out ??

Comment: Did you drag the folder on yhen?

Answer (score 6):

Just download OmniGraffle and then go to File->Open->Select your XcodeProject file and that's it you'll have a class diagram.

If your Project is quite big then you can use [github.com/nst/objc_dep](https://github.com/nst/objc_dep) to generate the .dot file and then open it with OmniGraffle it worked, but not for CircleGraph type.

- if you create methods/instance variables via @property's it won't list them

For other alternatives you can see [class-modeling-alternatives-for-objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061583/class-modeling-alternatives-for-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

If you try PiyushSharma solution and it not work. I think you should check "File->Open->Select your Xcode **folder**" instead " File->Open->Select your XcodeProject file". It means: dragging its (.xcodeproj) **containing folder** onto the OmniGraffle application icon

Best luck for you,